# running a processing applet in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, processing

I have downloaded and installed the processing IDE from their official website, then I followed the instructions on how to import the libraries into eclipse. I have core.jar, gluegen-rt.jar and jogl-all.jar added to path. I have the code below which I'm trying to run but when I go to the run menu there is no run options whatsoever. I only see 'run configurations'. Is there anything I'm missing?

```
package week2;
import processing.core.*;

public class ProcessingTest extends PApplet{

    private String URL = "https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5254/5428199232_c3678ed2ac.jpg";
    private PImage backgroundImg;

    public void setup()
    {
        size(800,  800);
        backgroundImg = loadImage(URL, "jpg");
        backgroundImg.resize(800, 800);
        background(backgroundImg);
    }
    public void draw()
    {

    }
    //public static void main(String args[]){
    //  PApplet.main(new String[]{"--present", "week2.ProcessingTest"});
    //}
}
```

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: I'm taking an online course that uses the processing library, but i decided to experiment a little bit on the side and downloaded the libraries from the official website instead of using the once given for the class. So now I'm running into problems when I try to run my code. Is there a way to write a Java application with the processing library?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Older versions of Processing were applet-based: `PApplet` extended `Applet`. This is no longer true as of Processing 3, so many people are still adjusting to the new lack of applets in Processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Processing 3, `PApplet` no longer extends `Applet` (more info [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes-in-3.0)). In other words, you can't run sketches as an applet anymore.

You'll have to put your `main` method back in and run it as an application instead.

If you really want to run as an applet, you'll have to create your own class that extends `Applet` or `JApplet`, and then add the Processing component to that. That can be pretty convoluted, plus applets are pretty much dead now anyway, so you're probably much better of deploying as an application- or even better, as JavaScript using [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/).

As a side note, you shouldn't have to rely on eclipse automatically detecting the run configuration. You should be able to go into the run configurations and create one yourself. That won't work for this specific case, but it's not a bad idea to get more comfortable with the "behind the scenes" stuff so cases like this are less confusing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Kevin. I pretty new to Java so I'm not sure how to work with those configurations yet but I'll get there with time. As far as the code I've posted above, when I uncomment the main method it runs but it runs in full screen and see nothing but a blank screen with a small darker square in the middle and the only way to exit out is Ctrl + F4, I have no idea why this happens, I've got the code for the main method from the processing website. Any ideas?

Comment: @JesseMyers You're using the `"--present"` option, which tells your sketch to be full-screen.

Comment: thank's for your help. removing the '--present' did the trick, but also the size() function cannot go into setup() anymore, you have to add it in a `public void settings()` method.